# Extract list data from a column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks really similar to this (basically a table of cities and their coordinates on a map. Note that coordinates is a list of X,Y values.

```
foo <- data.frame(
  city = c("chicago", "new york"), 
  coordinate = I(list(list(10, 15), list(20, 25))), 
  myabbr = c("chi", "ny")
)

bar <- subset(foo, select=c("city", "coordinate"))
```

Right now, I can create a new table of only the city and the coordinates. I really want the X and Y values to be a separate column. This is what I tried

```
bar <- subset(foo, select=c("city", "coordinate[1]", "coordinate[2]"))
```

I'm not sure exactly how to do this though.

Comment: You can try something like `cbind(as.character(bar$city), apply(bar, 1, function(i)unlist(i$coordinate)))`

Comment: I'll give that a shot

Comment: Maybe `cbind(foo, do.call(rbind, lapply(foo$coordinate, unlist)))` ?

Comment: That worked @zx8754. They both did technically, but that one had the proper datatypes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more option for you, use `listCol_w` from `splitstackshape`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_w(foo, "coordinate")
#       city myabbr coordinate_fl_1 coordinate_fl_2
#1:  chicago    chi              10              15
#2: new york     ny              20              25
```

Comment: Because you depend on a highly specific package I can tell you that most R developers would just use the internal `[[` function. Everyone will understand it whereas `listCol_w` needs a comment to be understood or looked up in the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can access a list Element with `list[[index]]`. In your case you can extract it this way:

```
foo <- data.frame(city=c("chicago", "new york"), coordinate=I(list(list(10, 15), list(20,25))), myabbr=c("chi", "ny"))
foo$coordinate_x = foo$coordinate[[1]]
foo$coordinate_y = foo$coordinate[[2]]
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to extract the X and Y elements from the list column "coordinate". List extraction is done like `list[[index]]` in R.

i.e.

```
foo <- data.frame(city=c("chicago", "new york"), coordinate=I(list(list(10, 15), list(20,25))), myabbr=c("chi", "ny"))

bar <- subset(foo, select=c("city", "coordinate"))

bar$x <- bar$coordinate[[1]]
bar$y <- bar$coordinate[[2]]

bar$coordinate <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually what I ended up using!

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is to `unlist` each row of your coordinates and `cbind` that with the cities, i.e.

```
cbind(city = as.character(bar$city), 
      setNames(data.frame(apply(bar, 1, function(i)unlist(i$coordinate))), 
               c('coordinate1', 'coordinate2')))
```

which gives,

> ```
>       city coordinate1 coordinate2
> 1  chicago          10          20
> 2 new york          15          25
> ```

Answer (score 2):

We can unlist the column and bind back to original dataframe, try:

```
cbind(foo, do.call(rbind, lapply(foo$coordinate, unlist)))
#       city coordinate myabbr  1  2
# 1  chicago     10, 15    chi 10 15
# 2 new york     20, 25     ny 20 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tidyverse as well

```
library(tidyverse)

foo %>% 
   mutate(coordinate=map(coordinate,~unlist(.) %>% 
                      paste(., collapse=","))) %>% 
   separate(coordinate, into = c("x", "y"), sep=",")
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  city     x     y     myabbr
  <fct>    <chr> <chr> <fct> 
1 chicago  10    15    chi   
2 new york 20    25    ny
```

This gives you the expected result

```
.Last.value %>% 
select(-myabbr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bar%>%
   group_by(city)%>%
   mutate(coordinate=list(unlist(coordinate)),
          n=list(paste0("coordinate",1:lengths(coordinate))))%>%
   unnest%>%
   spread(n,coordinate)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   city [2]
  city     coordinate1 coordinate2
  <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1 chicago          10.         15.
2 new york         20.         25.
```